# Groovy Jmeter collecting elements of an XML in a list

Tags: groovy

I have an xml string which I get from response of an HTTP like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Specification xmlns="TestSpecification.xsd">
  <Cases>
    <Case>
        <Name>foo</Name>
        <Desc>foo1</Desc>
        <Begin>
          <ABC>0</ABC>
          <DEF>0</DEF>
        </Begin>
        <Perms>
            <TYPE1>
              <ABC>7</ABC>
              <DEF>8</DEF>
            </TYPE1>
            <TYPE2>
              <Perm>
                <PermNo>1</PermNo>
                <Description>Perm 1</Description>
                <ABC>5</ABC>
                <DEF>0</DEF>
                <GHI>1</GHI>
                <JKL>2</JKL>
              </Perm>
              <Perm>
                <PermNo>2</PermNo>
                <Description>Perm 1</Description>
                <ABC>5</ABC>
                <DEF>0</DEF>
                <GHI>1</GHI>
                <JKL>2</JKL>
              </Perm>
              <Perm>
                <PermNo>2</PermNo>
                <Description>Perm 1</Description>
                <ABC>5</ABC>
                <DEF>0</DEF>
                <GHI>3</GHI>
                <JKL>4</JKL>                
              </Perm>
            </TYPE2>          
        </Perms>    
    </Case>
  </Cases>
</Specification>
```

I need to be able to retrieve all elements between (ABC's DEF's, GHI's and etc) in one list how can i do it pls. Note the Perms are variable and can be x many.

I have tried this in a loop by getting begin and end indexes and each block as "detail" to get data but I am afraid it might be fragile

```
ABC= (detail =~ "ABC>(.*)</ABC")[0][1]
```

thanks

Comment: Xml you provided is not parsable xml. Provide proper xml.

Comment: I am using dummy values here

Comment: values are not the problem, structure of xml is an issue. for instance you are not closing <Case> or <Cases> ...

Comment: yes I just fixed it

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job:

```
package test
/**
 * A simple application that parses a String that contains XML information using XmlSlurper.
 */
class Test {
    static stringXML = '''
  <Cases>
    <Case>
        <Name>foo</Name>
        <Desc>foo1</Desc>
        <Begin>
          <ABC>0</ABC>
          <DEF>0</DEF>
        </Begin>
        <Perms>
            <TYPE1>
              <ABC>7</ABC>
              <DEF>8</DEF>
            </TYPE1>
            <TYPE2>
              <Perm>
                <PermNo>1</PermNo>
                <Description>Perm 1</Description>
                <ABC>5</ABC>
                <DEF>0</DEF>
                <GHI>1</GHI>
                <JKL>2</JKL>
              </Perm>
              <Perm>
                <PermNo>2</PermNo>
                <Description>Perm 1</Description>
                <ABC>5</ABC>
                <DEF>0</DEF>
                <GHI>1</GHI>
                <JKL>2</JKL>
              </Perm>
              <Perm>
                <PermNo>2</PermNo>
                <Description>Perm 1</Description>
                <ABC>5</ABC>
                <DEF>0</DEF>
                <GHI>3</GHI>
                <JKL>4</JKL>
              </Perm>
            </TYPE2>
        </Perms>
    </Case>
  </Cases>
'''
   static main(args) {    
    def cases = new XmlSlurper().parseText(stringXML)
    def all = []
    ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'JKL'].each{ tag ->
      def list = cases.depthFirst().findAll { it.name() == tag }
      println tag + ":" + list
      all += list
    }
    println all

    }
}
```

You set the list of tags, then iterate over them with `each`. `cases` variable holds parsed xml and with depthFirst, you are getting all nodes, that are filtered then with findAll to match node name.